# QWebView on Qt4 and Qt5

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qwebview

I have a problem. I need to compile qt5 code on qt4. When I'm compiling it I have such error(on qt5 I haven't it):

```
QWebView: No Such File Or Directory
```

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui xml webkitwidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TPDetector
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    VKAuth.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
    VKAuth.h
```

How I can build my project on qt4?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New webkit shipping with QT5 has a new structure. QWebView, QWebpage, etc. are now part of QtWebKitWidgets.

So in your code you need to include webview like this:

```
  #include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
```

and in your .pro file your need to add:

```
   QT += webkitwidgets
```

If you really want to make your code forward/backwards compatible; I would just have a check for QT5:

```
   QT+= core gui webkit

   contains(QT_VERSION, ^5.*) {
       QT += webkitwidgets
   } 
   ...
```

and then in your code:

```
  #if (QT_VERSION < 0x050000)
  #include <QWebView>
  #else 
  #include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
  #endif
```

Answer (score 10):

I had to add the `libqtwebkit-dev` package for my app to compile.